# Generating permutations for all possible lengths

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I know there is a lot about permutations but I am looking for a more extended version.

Say in this very simple example I have {1,2,3,4} and my resulting set would be:

```
{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{2,3,4}
```

So you can see I am looking for an algorithm or solution that would help me find all permutations of length `1,2,...,n-1.`

I hope I have provided enough information for you to help me.

Comment: These are not permutations; rather, they are all subsets of the given set. The question is a duplicate.

Comment: That looks like a [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) without the original set and the empty set.

Comment: The usage of powerset is extremely useful it would seem :) Thank you soo much.